# Scala - pattern matching - Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I'm getting a String of comma-separated metric values and then using the String for an SQL query.

However when I'm trying to pattern-match, there's an  Error here: `Some(newMetrics)` - `option Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type, found: Some[A], required: String`

What is the right way to use pattern-matching in this case?

```
val metrics: String = props.getProperty(NEW_METRICS).filter(StringUtils.isNotBlank).getOrElse("")

val metricsQuery = metrics match {
  case Some(newMetrics) => s"""SELECT $newMetrics FROM ${metricsTable}"""
  case _ => OLD_TABLE
}
```

Comment: Your metrics are already an string, not an option. Either remove the `getOrElse("")` or change the `""` with `OLD_TABLE` in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to match a `String` as if it were an `Option[String]`

By leaving out the `.getOrElse("")` `metrics` will be of type `Option[String]` and you can match it as you did in the lower part of your example.